# Tomcat: block requests for certain paths for requests coming from certain interfaces

Tags: security, tomcat, filter

Is there an open source filter that I can use on Tomcat to prevent access to certain path (say /a/b/*) when the request comes from a given interface?

The use case: I have REST services deployed on Tomcat that should only be accessed by the application itself, but which for security reasons should not be accessible from the outside world. I could do this in Apache, if Apache was used as a front-end, but in this case it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's an open source one that you can use, but [writing one](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that checks where does a request come from is quite easy.

See [getPathTranslated()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathTranslated()), [getRemoteAddr](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr()), etc.

yc